# How to use Nuxt.js components in a WordPress project?

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a large Nuxt.js project with many different components. Now I want to reuse these components in a new project which uses WordPress. So for example I want to be able to display a certain component on a WordPress page or post.

My first thought was to only use Vue.js without Nuxt but then I would not be able to use the Nuxt components without having to remove Nuxt-specific code. I know that there is also a way to use Nuxt programmatically as a middleware but I can't figure out how to do this with WordPress.

Can someone guide me into the right direction?

Comment: Nuxt is a framework, not a library of components (eg buefy or vuetify). What components are you trying to abstract out that are nuxt specific? or is it that you have a nuxt site and you wish to share some of the components you built within the nuxt site with your wordpress site?

Comment: Right, it's a Nuxt site which means components can have Nuxt specific code like `this.$nuxt` etc. I want to share those components with my WordPress site.

Comment: The inherit problem here is that nuxt acts as either an SPA or a universal web application running with SSR mode and bound to a port on a server. You would have to have the entire nuxt application mounted within the given wordpress page in order to gain access to this. It's just not reasonable possible.